# New \settitles command

Tags: beamer, sectioning

I'm new in LaTeX and i'm currently trying to modify a `.sty` in order to have my own presentation style (I often need to make new presentations).

What I'm trying to do is to create a `\settitles` command that automatically sets my frame's title and subtitle according to my section and subsection names.

A brief example. Currently I have this code:

```
\section{My first section}
\subsection{My first subsection}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{My first section}
  \framesubtitle{My first subsection}
  bla-bla-bla
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{My first section}
  \framesubtitle{My first subsection}
  bli-bli-bli
\end{frame}

\subsection{My second subsection}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{My first section}
  \framesubtitle{My second subsection}
blo-blo-blo
\end{frame}
```

Because I find this redundant and because all my frames titles are matched with section and subsection names, I would try to modify my `.sty` file so I can write

```
\section{My first section}
\subsection{My first subsection}
\begin{frame}
  \settitles
  bla-bla-bla
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \settitles
  bli-bli-bli
\end{frame}

\subsection{My second subsection}
\begin{frame}
  \settitles
blo-blo-blo
\end{frame}
```

Even if I don't know much about LaTeX I've began to work on this by searching Google and I found this code that seems to be a first step:

```
\newcommand{\sectiontitle}{}
\newcommand{\newsection}[1]{\section{#1}\renewcommand{\sectiontitle}{#1}}

\newcommand{\subsectiontitle}{}
\newcommand{\newsubsection}[1]{\subsection{#1}\renewcommand{\subsectiontitle}{#1}}
```

I've insered this code in my `.sty` file (I have a customized theme based on `Rochester` and now I can type just

```
\newsection{My first section}
\newsubection{My first subsection}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{\sectiontitle}
  \framesubtitle{\subsectiontitle}
  bla-bla-bla
\end{frame}
```

I've also created this command

```
\newcommand{\settitles}{\frametitle{\sectiontitle} \framesubtitle{\subsectiontitle}}
```

I feel that I'm almost there but now i have to change `\newsection` into `\section`. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do can be done simply using `\insertsectionhead` and  `\insertsubsectionhead`:

```
\newcommand\settitle{
    \frametitle{\insertsectionhead}
    \framesubtitle{\insertsubsectionhead}
}
```

An additional advantage now is that a frame appears before a \subsection command has been used, no subtitle is produced (See example below). A complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand\settitle{
    \frametitle{\insertsectionhead}
    \framesubtitle{\insertsubsectionhead}
}

\begin{document}

\section{My first section}
\subsection{First subsection of the first section}
\begin{frame}
\settitle
test
\end{frame}

\subsection{Second subsection of the first section}
\begin{frame}
\settitle
test
\end{frame} 

\section{My second section}
\begin{frame}
\settitle
test
\end{frame}

\subsection{First subsection of the second section}
\begin{frame}
\settitle
test
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

If this is going to be done for every frame, you can even automate the process without having to manually invoke `\settile` for every frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@frameenv{%
  \def\beamer@process@envbody{\endgroup%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\beamer@framecommand\expandafter\beamer@frameoptions\expandafter{\the\beamer@envbody}}%
  \global\beamer@envbody{}\def\beamer@begin@stack{b}%
  \begingroup
  \let\frame\beamer@collect@@body
  \def\beamer@process@envbody{\frame}%
  \beamer@process@envbody%
     \frametitle{\insertsectionhead}
    \framesubtitle{\insertsubsectionhead}
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{My first section}
\subsection{First subsection of the first section}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\subsection{Second subsection of the first section}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame} 

\section{My second section}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\subsection{First subsection of the second section}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Of course, in a `.sty` file you'd only use

```
\def\beamer@frameenv{%
  \def\beamer@process@envbody{\endgroup%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\beamer@framecommand\expandafter\beamer@frameoptions\expandafter{\the\beamer@envbody}}%
  \global\beamer@envbody{}\def\beamer@begin@stack{b}%
  \begingroup
  \let\frame\beamer@collect@@body
  \def\beamer@process@envbody{\frame}%
  \beamer@process@envbody%
     \frametitle{\insertsectionhead}
    \framesubtitle{\insertsubsectionhead}
 }
```

without `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
After exchange some though I decided to rewrote my answer:

One way to obtain what you wish is use `hyperref` packages and its `namref` option. With it I define new variant f section which include autogenerated labels. They are used in definition of `\settitle`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{hyperref}

\let\oldsection\section
\let\oldsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\oldsection{#1}\label{sec:\thesection}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{\oldsubsection{#1}\label{sec:\thesubsection}}

\newcommand{\settitle}{
    \frametitle{\nameref{sec:\thesection}}\framesubtitle{\nameref{sec:\thesubsection}}
                    }

    \begin{document}
\section{My first section}

\subsection{My first subsection}

\begin{frame}\settitle
  bla-bla-bla
\end{frame}

\subsection{My second subsection}
\begin{frame}\settitle
blo-blo-blo
\end{frame} 
    \end{document}
```

I hope that this solution is close enough to your wish. This solution has some limitation. It require, that in presentation can not be lonely section. To it should always follows subsection, otherwise, for frame subtitle will be used last subsection.

[image]

Comment: i've seen this solution by searching google but it doesn't entirely statisfy me because i still have to label every section and to adapt the good label in each \nameref{}. 

A \settitles command that automatically matches the titles without naming them would be more handy

Comment: Some how you need to tell to `frametitle`` and `framesubtitle` which section title you have in mind. Iif you define labels such that for example to follow section number, you will obtain "handy" solution ...

Comment: With the code i've written so far i am very close to what i wanted :

Just need to have \section instead of \newsection ...

Comment: `\let\section\newsection` ?